# Calculating minimum sample size required for repeated measures linear mixed model using the simr package

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, simulation, statistical-power

I would like to use the `simr` package to calculate the smallest sample size needed to achieve $0.80$ power at the $0.05$ alpha level while accounting for a small effect size. My study is a repeated measures performance task, where my model needs to consider the following which is applied to all participants:

- $1$ continuous predictor (sleep).
- $1$ continuous outcome (reaction time).
- $1$ grouping variable with three levels ("low", "medium", "high").

The `simr` package appears to calculate simulations based on an alpha level of $0.05$, a power level of $0.80$, and a small effect size, but I do not see how I would account for the repeated measures aspect of the study.

I have run two versions of code, but they give very different answers (one says ~$50$, the other says ~$190$). Can anyone please help formulate the necessary code to calculate the minimum sample size needed for this study?

Comment: A "small" effect here may be arbitrary. What do you know about the effects in general? Do you know of any regressions in the past that have coefficients which you can utilize? If so, I actually think the `mixedpower` package does a lot better job if you have strong a priori assumptions before running the PA. [This paper](https://link.springer.com/10.3758/s13428-021-01546-0) does an excellent job of showing how to combine the two, and has some useful Notebooks for doing this as well.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand - thank you so much for recommending an alternative! I am new to R, so I very much appreciate the suggestion! At present, we do not have any a priori assumptions and there is a lack of literature in the specific domain we are exploring which means we are quite exploratory in nature which is why we were trying a simulation-based approach (my variables in the post were just examples as opposed to the true ones). I will certainly give the paper you suggested a read and test!

Comment: That's okay. I show an example with my answer below, and the articles/books I reference should provide a launching pad for your inquiry.

Answer (score 3):

##### Some Background

Since you don't have a strong idea yet of what effects to expect, I recommend that you try to find articles that cover this to a degree. There is a lot of reaction time studies out there, so this shouldn't be an issue so much as the effects of interest and how much you expect them to deviate. These don't have to be exact. They just need to reflect your best guess. I will note that reaction time is a bit special. It typically takes on an inverse Gaussian distribution (aka extremely right skewed), and thus requires transformation using the $\text{invRT}$ transformation proposed by Brysbaert or simply using a GLMM with an inverse Gaussian family error term. Actually, the original canonical paper on the `lme4` package is based on a reaction time sleep deprivation study which may interest you (see Bates et al., 2014).

As I noted, the `mixedpower` package may be helpful in your case. It is quite flexible in that you can specify your simulated power analysis by raw data that you have on hand or some a priori specification of what you expect the effects to be. This requires some finesse, as you need to know how beta coefficients work in regression and a bit about how R works with regression as well. But the tools are there and with some knowledge of R, this can be made surprisingly simple.

##### Example Simulation

Below is an example of a power simulation based off the `mixedpower` paper. Much of this comes from the actual paper, but I provide a much simpler code here with some annotations to make it clear what is going on. I assume you have the other packages here, else you should install them as well:

```
#### Run This to Install Mixed Power ####
devtools::install_github("DejanDraschkow/mixedpower") # along with other packs

#### Load Libaries ####
library(mixedpower)
library(lme4)
library(simr)
```

The example they give is a crossed effects mixed model, which multiplies the subject by item observations. You may not need to account for this in your model. I simply explain what is going on here. First you simulate the number of subjects, the number of items, and then combine them into one data frame.

```
#### Create 20 Subjects ####
subject_ID <- (1:20)

#### Create 100 Words ####
stimuli_ID <- (1:100)

#### Combine Them ####
artificial_data <- expand.grid(Subject = subject_ID,
                               Word = stimuli_ID)
```

Once you achieve that, we can add two fixed effects, a categorical variable for native vs non-native language group, and word frequency ratings. We create $1,000$ observations and then add them to the data frame.

```
#### Make Identifier for Native Language ####
native_language <- c(rep(-0.5, 1000),
                     rep(0.5, 1000))

#### Generate Frequency Ratings ####
frequency_ratings <- rnorm(100,
                           mean = 5,
                           sd = 1) # 100 frequency ratings (one for every word)

#### Add to Data Frame ###
artificial_data["NativeLanguage"] <- native_language
artificial_data["Frequency"] <- rep(frequency_ratings, 20) # multiply by 20 (for every subject)
artificial_data$CenteredFrequency <- scale(artificial_data$Frequency, scale = F)
```

Now we need to specify what we expect the effects to be for our beta coefficients (the slopes/intercepts):

```
#### Specify Beta Coefficients for Fixed Effects ####
fixed_effects <-  c(-4.3, 0.35, -0.4, -0.32) # order follows the order in model summary and formula
```

Finally, we specify what we want our random effects variances to be:

```
#### Set Random Effect Variance ####
random_variance <- list(1.04, 0.65)
```

We have done most of the heavy lifting so far. Now we just fit a fake model which inputs all of effects we have specified:

```
#### Create GLMM ####
artificial_glmer <- makeGlmer(Correct
                              ~ NativeLanguage 
                              * CenteredFrequency 
                              + (1 | Subject)
                              + (1 | Word),
                              family = "binomial", 
                              fixef = fixed_effects,
                              VarCorr = random_variance,
                              data = artificial_data)
```

If we inspect our model with `summary(artificial_glmer)`, we should see the same fixed and random effects we asked for:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Correct ~ NativeLanguage * CenteredFrequency + (1 | Subject) +      (1 | Word)
   Data: artificial_data

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   757.1    790.7   -372.6    745.1     1994 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.5992 -0.2671 -0.2227 -0.1913  4.0821 

Random effects:
 Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Word    (Intercept) 1.04     1.0198  
 Subject (Intercept) 0.65     0.8062  
Number of obs: 2000, groups:  Word, 100; Subject, 20

Fixed effects:
                                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                       -4.3000     0.2312 -18.595  < 2e-16 ***
NativeLanguage                     0.3500     0.2845   1.230 0.218603    
CenteredFrequency                 -0.4000     0.1075  -3.721 0.000199 ***
NativeLanguage:CenteredFrequency  -0.3200     0.1979  -1.617 0.105862    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) NtvLng CntrdF
NativeLangg -0.016              
CntrdFrqncy -0.002 -0.005       
NtvLngg:CnF -0.004  0.003 -0.081
```

Now that our model is specified, we simply run the power analysis. We input our previously specified model and data, note that we want the fixed effects of native language and frequency, we ask for the subject estimates (for how many subjects we need in this design), how many subjects we want to estimate (from $20$ subjects to $180$, the critical value we need to surpass ($2$ here is a simplification for the $1.96$ cutoff in NHST tests), the number of simulations (should be large like $100$ or $1,000$ but here I use $10$ to make it faster), and the smallest effect size of interest (SESOI), which is explained in the article).

```
#### Run Mixedpower Sim ####
power <- mixedpower(model = artificial_glmer,
                    data = artificial_data,
                    fixed_effects = c("NativeLanguage",
                                      "CenteredFrequency"),
                    simvar = "Subject",
                    steps = c(20,60,100,140,180),
                    critical_value = 2, 
                    n_sim = 100,
                    SESOI = c(-4.3,  0.30 ,-0.34, -0.27))
```

This will take *a long time*. I recommend adjusting this to have a lower number of simulations and steps to first see what it is doing. Once you know the basics, then you can run the power analysis in full. In any case, once it is finally over, you plot the results with the code `multiplotPower(power)`, which gives you this by-subject estimation of the power. I unfortunately cannot run this on my computer at the moment, but it should look something like this:

[image]

One important point. You mentioned you are new to R. I heavily recommend that you have a strong foundation in both R and regression before doing all of this. I highly recommend *Regression and Other Stories* for learning about both. It is in my opinion a required test for running any regression in R, and while mixed models are not explicitly mentioned, their other older book talks about it at length. Both are listed below in the references. However, the multilevel regression book is fairly outdated, and there is supposedly a new one on the horizon next year.

##### References

- Bates, D., Mächler, M., Bolker, B., & Walker, S. (2015). Fitting linear mixed-effects models using lme4. Journal of Statistical Software, 67(1). https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v067.i01
- Gelman, A., & Hill, J. (2007). Data analysis using regression and multilevel/hierarchical models. Cambridge University Press.
- Gelman, A., Hill, J., & Vehtari, A. (2022). Regression and other stories. Cambridge University Press.
- Kumle, L., Võ, M. L.-H., & Draschkow, D. (2021). Estimating power in (generalized) linear mixed models: An open introduction and tutorial in R. Behavior Research Methods, 53, 2528–2543. https://doi.org/10.3758/s13428-021-01546-0

Comment: thank you again for that. The paper was quite detailed which was helpful for the first introduction to it. I agree that a stronger foundation in R would be best, but I am unfortunately on a tight time frame, and I cannot see alternatives to R (such as G*power) that can do an LMM power analysis which is such a shame. I will keep re-visiting this to build my knowledge base.